# Eventful API: Searching for events at a particular place

Tags: search

I'm searching for events at a particular place and also successfully retrieving all the events. But suppose I'm getting about 1500 events as "total_items" and the first page of response shows up the first 10 events.Then how could I reach to the remaining set of events, there isn't any "next page link".
And the most important question that are there any restrictions or upgradation plan for Eventful. Just because I was not able to find the required answers on their web portal. I'm posting it over here.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 10 events as default page size is 10 .If you want to change page size ,you can change it in your query.
http://api.eventful.com/rest/events/search?l=GREEN+BAY+WEST&page_size=100
In the above query it will return 100 events,you can get 100 events per page maximum.
If you want to go to next page,you can change page_number in your query.